# How to create database in TestContainers?

Tags: testcontainers

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

this is the Container, lauched with my tests:

```
@ClassRule
public static PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer()
    .withDatabaseName("user")
    .withUsername("postgres")
    .withPassword("postgres");
```

but when i'm trying to stablish connection to database `user` i'm receiving exception:

```
PSQLException: FATAL: database "user" does not exist
```

In this container only present default DB `"postgres"`.

How to create database `"user"`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because container return JDBC_URL with random port, and by the default port is accessible default Postgres DB, but thee neede one is on random port

this is the workaround:

```
@ClassRule
public static DockerComposeContainer environment =
    new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/docker-compose-postgres.yml"))
        .withExposedService("postgres-it", 5432);
```

this is the docker-compose yml:

```
version: "2"
    services:
    postgres-it:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        hostname: postgres-it
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: user
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this test](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/6b084547dccd3ccf39a6fb648d9dbbe41838a8a3/modules/jdbc-test/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/junit/CustomizablePostgreSQLTest.java#L19) from TestContainers project with DB_NAME set to "user" and USER/PWD set to "postgres", the result was successful. 
Make sure you configure your connection correctly, or consider [JDBC-style containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/database_containers.html#jdbc-url).